# How to implement AppLovin Reward Video in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add reward video from AppLovin to my application. Interstitial is work perfectly. But Reward video return "LOADREWARDEDFAILED".

Here is the part where I initialize

```
AppLovin.SetSdkKey(SDKKey);
AppLovin.InitializeSdk();
AppLovin.PreloadInterstitial();
AppLovin.LoadRewardedInterstitial();
AppLovin.SetUnityAdListener("ApplovinListener");
// AppLovin.SetTestAdsEnabled("true");
```

Here is the part where should be show

```
if (AppLovin.IsIncentInterstitialReady())
    AppLovin.ShowRewardedInterstitial();
else
    AppLovin.LoadRewardedInterstitial();
```

Message from xcode:

> LOADREWARDEDFAILED
>   ApplovinListener:onAppLovinEventReceived(String)

Comment: Can you tell us which line of code throws the error ?

Comment: AppLovin.LoadRewardedInterstitial();

Comment: Alternatively, you can refer to their docs: https://dash.applovin.com/docs/integration#iosUnityRewardedVideos